# GeoLocation inside a promise

Tags: javascript, geolocation, async-await, es6-promise

I want to place navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() method inside a promise and later await for it inside a async function. Is this the right way?

```js
const getGeoLocation = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  function positionSuccess(position) {
    resolve(position);
  }
  function error() {
    reject();
  }
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, error, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
});

export default getGeoLocation;
```

Comment: Looks good, but since you're not doing any additional processing on your result, why not just pass `resolve` and `reject` directly into the `getCurrentPosition` call? EG: `getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, { enableHighAccuracy: true })`.

Answer (score 8):

```
var getPosition = function (options) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
  });
}

getPosition()
  .then((position) => {
    console.log(position);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
  });
```