# How to prevent the browser coordinates to load after the async API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I'm trying to load weather data with React and for that you need the browser coordinates. I have tried the loading with both async and sync and in both cases it does not load before the API response that is async. How to prevent that?

```
    const fetchBrowserCoordinates = () => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log('GeoLocation is not supported by your browser.');
    } else {
        console.log('Loading.');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                console.log('Loaded coordinates.');
                setCoords(position.coords);
            },
            () => { console.log('Unable to retrieve your location.'); }
        );
    }
}
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRealTimeWeatherData();
  }, []);

const fetchRealTimeWeatherData = async () => {
    fetchBrowserCoordinates();

    const API_KEY = '____YOUR____API____KEY____';
    const location = coords.latitude + ',' + coords.longitude;

    await fetch('https://api.tomorrow.io/v4/weather/realtime?units=imperial&location=' + location + '&apikey=' + API_KEY, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => setWeather(response))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));

    console.log(weather);
}
```

The response that I'm getting from the API is an error because the coordinates are being passed as undefined.

https://api.tomorrow.io/v4/weather/realtime?units=imperial&location=undefined,undefined&apikey=____YOUR____API____KEY____ 400

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: a) you're not `await`ing the `fetchBrowserCoordinates` call b) `fetchBrowserCoordinates` [needs to return a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47984873/1048572). c) Why are you calling `setCoords` in `fetchBrowserCoordinates` instead of attempting to return the coords to the caller? Where do `coords` come from in `fetchRealTimeWeatherData`?

Comment: I had to adjust a bit the code provided by Fatorice and @bergi, things are working fine. Thanks Bergi for explaining me how Promises actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the update of a react state variable doesn't happen immediately. So you update the coords variable, but when you access the latitude/longitude properties, the coords variable hasn't been updated yet. My advice is to refactor the `fetchBrowserCoordinates` to directly return the coordinates like this:

```
const fetchBrowserCoordinates = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        reject("Not available");
    } else {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                resolve(position);
            },
            reject
        );
    }
    });
}
```

Then you can fetch the data from the API like that:

```
const fetchRealTimeWeatherData = async () => {
    const newCoords = await fetchBrowserCoordinates();

    const API_KEY = '____YOUR____API____KEY____';
    const location = newCoords.latitude + ',' + newCoords.longitude;

    await fetch('https://api.tomorrow.io/v4/weather/realtime?units=imperial&location=' + location + '&apikey=' + API_KEY, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => setWeather(response))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));

    console.log(weather); // this won't show the latest response due to reasons explained above
    setCoords(newCoords);
}
```

Optionally you can do the `fetchBrowserCoordinates` only once, e.g. if their already coords present from a weather API fetch before. Hope that helped you!